# Accessing specific object in .JSON file and creating select menu

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm creating select menu with data being passed from .JSON file, however my .JSON file has 2 arrays and i need to pass the only `country[]` array. I have written some code but it doesn't work. any help ?

My .JS file

```js
let dropdown = document.getElementById("listCountry");
dropdown.length = 0;

let deafultOption = document.createElement('option');
deafultOption.text = 'Countries';

dropdown.add(deafultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

fetch('fleet.json')  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = data[i].name;
          option.value = data[i].abbreviation;
          dropdown.add(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
```

My .JSON file

```json
{
    "country": [
    { "id": 1, "name" : "England" },
    { "id": 2, "name" : "Holland" },
    { "id": 3, "name" : "France" },
    { "id": 4, "name" : "Russia" }
    ],
    
    "ship": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Greenwich", "speed" : 12, "country_id" : 1 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Eendracht", "speed" : 22, "country_id" : 2 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Kingfisher", "speed" : 10, "country_id" : 1 },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Fury", "speed" : 12, "country_id" : 1 },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Hercule", "speed" : 33, "country_id" : 3 },
    { "id": 6, "name": "Licorne", "speed" : 33, "country_id" : 3 },
    { "id": 7, "name": "Arkhangel Gavriil", "speed" : 44, "country_id" : 4 }
    ]
}
```

Maybe I couldn't express my question, that's why I demonstrated with the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Data is an object, you seem to want the array?

Comment: `data` will be an object, with fields `country` and `ship` in it. You want to run your loop on `data.country`.

Comment: Side comment: in contemporary browsers you can use [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which you may find useful if you do not need `i` for other purposes.

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I want the array exactly

Answer (score 0):

Replace `data` with `data.country` in your .then handler (you want the array defined by the `country` key but you are looping over the whole JSON object instead). Also replace ".add" with ".appendChild".

One last note: none of the objects have an "abbreviation" property defined so the value of each element will be undefined, which will cause more issues later. So be sure to add abbreviations to the JSON or find a different way to define the `value` property for each option.

Comment: replacing `data` with `data.country` didn't work, could you show the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over `data.country`. Put this in where you have `response.json().then()`.

```js
response.json().then(function(data) {  
   let option;
   const countries = data.country;
   // Array.prototype.forEach() iterates over all values in an array
   countries.forEach(cont => {
       option = document.createElement('option');
       option.text = cont.name;
       dropdown.add(option);
   });
});
```

Comment: you may need to change the code a bit to work, (i do see an error let me fix it though)